# Specify source of a row when we append dataframes

Tags: python-3.x

Example file:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

I am using for loop to append all the *.csv data. Then will use the `appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=0)`. All the files are contained in the same folder.

My code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2019, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2019, 1, 3)
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
  appended_data = []
  for infile in glob.glob("path/*.csv"):
    data = pd.read_csv(infile, header=3, sep=";",encoding = 'unicode_escape')
    data['Source']= single_date
    appended_data.append(data)

appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=0)
appended_data.to_csv('appended.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a new list for `appended_data` for each new date, so your resulting appended.csv will only have the data for the last day. Move `appended_data = []` out from that loop:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

appended_data = []
start_date = date(2019, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2019, 1, 3)
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
  for infile in glob.glob("path/*.csv"):
    data = pd.read_csv(infile, header=3, sep=";",encoding = 'unicode_escape')
    data['Source']= single_date
    appended_data.append(data)

appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=0)
appended_data.to_csv('appended.csv')
```

This will result in the same data being duplicated with a different `Source`, so your `infile` loop may need to check that you are only appending the files that you want for that day.